# Rails HABTM filter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-and-belongs-to-many

I feel like what I am doing is very, VERY simple, and all of the resources I've found are more complicated and attempting to replicate them or simplify them leaves me confused.

I have two objects (Stories and Characters) with a HABTM relationship.

My goal is to be able to list all Stories that involve a particular character.

If I do Story.where("stories_characters.character_id = 17"), I get an error that it can't find a column called "stories_characters.character_id" in my story table.

What is the correct way to go about this?

I understand that there is join table weirdness, but every example I saw was filtering on BOTH ids, and not just one...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have a join table?  You must have a join table named characters_stories with columns named character.id and story.id.  I believe that is a requirement for HABTM.  In your models, you need to define:

Story

```
:has_and_belongs_to_many => :characters
```

Character

```
:has_and_belongs_to_many => :stories
```

Once you have it all wired up, you should be able to just do:

```
char = Character.find(17)
char.stories
```

Comment: Oh god, I feel pretty dumb now.  I was so busy looking for sql statements and other weirdness that it didn't occur to me that of COURSE I already have the Character, I just need a list of it's story sections.  I should know better than to code so early in the morning ^_^;;  Thank you!